Swift Compiler Error (Xcode) on VScode flutter project with IOS simulator
I'm new to flutter and I've been working on this side project for awhile. I switched over the project from my linux laptop over to a mac and I'm having trouble trying to launch the app to the ios simulator eventhough the Chrome version works fine. It builds in Xcode but doesn't build to ios. This is the error I'm getting with swift's compiler. A step-by-step explanation of how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Here's the error. And the ide I'm using is vscode.
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 16 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            3.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/yonathendesisa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InA
ppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1225:25


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16.



Please refer thsis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79016827/swift-compiler-error-xcode-method-does-not-override-any-after-updating
