"Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass" error after updating Xcode
After updating my macOS version to 15.0 and updating Xcode to Version 16.0, my application can't get compiled and shows me this error:

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/userName/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1235:25
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPad Air 13-inch (M2).

For sure it's because of the new Xcode update, but how do I solve it?
I tried:

changing some code in InAppWebView.swift:1235:25 file that I think can work.
cleaning the project.

Both did not help.

To solve the error on iOS (Android requires more changes):

upgrade to the latest flutter version: flutter upgrade
then run flutter pub upgrade --major-versions: this will get the most updated and compatibility versions of the packages in Android and IOS and flutter
then just run flutter clean && flutter pub get


Still problem exist...

error only exist in ios :
Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1225:25
Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:876:20

Try to update your xcode to the latest version and give it another try if not my minimum IOS version for the application in the Profile part of the ios is 15, give that a try. beside that if you use the flutter_html package my version is  3.0.0-beta.2 and  if these thing not working i really dont know because your error is the same as mine

Please try the solution mentioned in this Stack Overflow answer:
 The  latest version of flutter_inappwebview, 6.1.0+1, has a fix for this issue.
Just update to version 6.1.0+1 in your pubspec.yaml, like this:
flutter_inappwebview: ^6.1.0+1
